# How to find the biggest filesize in a large directory

Tags: find, osx, size

I have a large directory, with too many files for just `ls`.  My idea: use something along the line of:

```
find . -name * -exec wc -c < {} \; | sort | tail -n 1
```

Problem: shell is interpreting it as (`find . -name * -exec wc -c`) < (`{} \;`) | ...

I need the "<" on the `< {}`, to avoid displaying the filename into `sort`.

I've also tried

```
find . -name "*" -exec cat {} +| wc -c
```

However, this seems to be interpreted as: (`find . -name "*" -exec cat {}`) | (`wc -c`) -- so it gives me the size of all files combined.

There is also a [variant using du](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10768/find-biggest-files-or-directories)-- however, since the biggest files could be just a few bytes apart, this just displays along the lines of a million files of 500-KB size-- again, too many for ls.

Comment: are there subdirectories within your *large directory* ?

Comment: What's the idea behind `-name *`?

Comment: No-- no subdirectories.  The idea behind `-name *` is to process all the files in this directory.  Maybe the script will work without it?

Comment: I'm not sure why this works at all: The `*` should get expanded and mess up the command. Leaving it away will process all files, using `-name "*" will process all but the dot-files.

Comment: But what's wrong about `du -b * .??* | sort -rn | head -n7`?

Comment: @Philippos if there really are a lot of files (thousands or maybe hundreds of thousands) the `*` will fail to expand.

Comment: But `ls -lS | sed 10q ` will work fine and should be faster than anything else, In particular, finding sizes with `wc -c` is just nuts.

Comment: @roaima Good explanation, thank you. Anyhow, relying on such a limitation is probably not the way to do things.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that none of your file names contains a newline (`\n`), and that you have GNU utilities, you can use this as a quick and dirty solution:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec stat --fmt $'%s\t%n' {} + | sort -n | tail -1
```

Remove `-maxdepth 1` if you have subdirectories that must be included in the search. If your `find` doesn't support the terminator `+` you can replace it with the less efficient `\;`. Change the format string to just `'%s'` if you don't want the filename output.

---

If you have file names with non-printing characters in them you can use this slower variant:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec stat --printf "%s\t" {} \; -print | sort -n | tail -1
```

Remove `-print` if you really don't want the filename output.

---

For OSX I think you can use a command like this, but I've no easy way of testing it. Remove `-print` if you don't want the filename output:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec stat -f '%z' -n {} \; -print | sort -n | tail -n 1
```

Comment: `stat: illegal option -- c`  Maybe I need to download a newer version somewhere?

Comment: @Alex try `--fmt` instead of `-c`. If that doesn't work please identify your OS and version of `stat` (on my Linux-based system, `stat --version` returns `stat (GNU coreutils) 8.26`).

Comment: `stat: illegal option -- -`

Comment: Right.  When I typed `stat --version`, that gave me the error I posted above.  I have whatever the newest version of Mac is right now.

Comment: Here is what I got to finally work: `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec stat -f %z {} \; | sort -n | tail -n 1`  In particular, the `-f` should have a % in front of the z, and `-print` is not required when I'm not looking for the name of that file, just its size.

Answer (score 2):

To print the largest file (with size in kilobytes), ***ls*** approach:

```
ls -S1s --block-size=K | sed -n '2{p;q;}'
```

---

- `-S` - sort by file size, largest first
- `-s` - print the allocated size of each file, in blocks
- `-1` - list one file per line
- `sed -n '2{p;q;}'` - the 1st line in `ls` output is the line with `total` size (e.g. `total 388K`). The 2nd line is the line containing the largest file with its size. This expression will consider only the 2nd needed line

Comment: It would help to know what the `2{p;q;}` does, but this worked.

Comment: This breaks with filenames containing newlines. (Unusual, but possible.)

Comment: @Alex the `2{p;q}` prints (`p`) the second line of output and then quits (`q`) so as not to bother reading the rest of the data stream.

Comment: @Alex, added some explanation

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Apparently, the '-s' option lists the files in 512-byte clusters.  So to find the size of the biggest one in *bytes*, the shortest solution I have found using your method is: `stat -f '%z' < "ls -S1 | head -n 1"` where the double-quotes would be ` characters.